# cnn feature extraction from an image, python

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I need to extract components of advertisement pages; first I need to detect and mark the buttons (little rectangles under the page where it's written 'click') of the web advertisement pages(I use these pages as images for my data.) and I've trained the data in order to detect buttons by CNN and it perfectly knows whether an image is a button or not. However, after I've trained the data, I have some troubles to label these detected buttons by CNN. I will be so glad for any suggestions. Here are the codes;

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten 
from keras.layers import Dense
#Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()
#Step 1: Convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation 
= 'relu')) 

#Step 2: Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (2,2)))

#Step 3:Flatten
classifier.add(Flatten())

#Step 4: Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

#Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics 
= ['accuracy'])

#Fitting the CNN to the Images from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train_set1',
                                                 target_size=(64, 64),
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_set1', target_size(64,64), 
batch_size=32,class_mode='binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch=2754, epochs=25, 
validation_data=test_set, nb_val_samples=460)
```

Comment: please read [ask] and improve your question. give examples, explain more. I don't even get your point. what is a button of an add page? and how can an image be a button? what about images that show a button or buttons that show an image?

Comment: I am so new on Python and Stackoverflow as well, you are right. I am working on page segmentation on  web advertisement pages and the button is the part of the page that you click to show the advertisement. I need to detect button part of these advertisement pages. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: That's not a problem related to your experience with Python or StackOverflow. Its more a matter of communication skills. You should at least not expect people to be able to read your mind ;)
Would it not be much easier and more reliable to just get that information from the page's source code? I mean just from looking at an image you cannot know if it has a link or not until you move your mouse over it.